# Upload fpga code from zynqmp to peripheral

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, fpga, xilinx

We have a complex embedded system with zynqmp processor running Xilinx's Linux and several other peripherals. Peripherals have fpgas and we would like to program peripherals in the field whenever there are changes to fpga code. These peripherals have jtag interface and TAP signals are mapped as gpios in zynqmp.

The fpga files are in svf, xsvf or some other format. I am looking for c/c++ code that can parse these files and update peripherals.

Do you have suggestions?

Thanks,

Comment: You should be able to find example player code for *one* of the files, typically backended by a "put your GPIO operation here" abstraction.  That aspect of your problem isn't really different than a hard-core MCU or SoC wanting to program an attached FPGA.  Slave serial may be simpler if you have the connection to support it.  Way back in the dark ages someone reversed the protocol for network-remote xilinx device programmers and implemented their own back end for that, too.

Answer (score 0):

"Peripherals have FPGAs". That does not make sense to me. You mean FPGA has peripheral IP blocks, right? Am also assuming you use Yocto/OpenEmbedded since that's how Xilinx provide Linux BSP support.

Xilinx SDK should have generated a HDF, which is [consumed](https://github.com/Xilinx/meta-xilinx-tools/blob/master/recipes-bsp/hdf/external-hdf.bb) by the Yocto build process. The BOOT.bin is what configures the FPGAs I believe, however, I am not sure of the internals. You can have a look at [meta-updater](https://github.com/advancedtelematic/meta-updater) or [meta-mender](https://github.com/mendersoftware/meta-mender) for your OTA update approach. To program the FPGA side IP blocks in field, update the BOOT.bin along with the Kernel and device tree. Would recommend double checking with a Xilinx FAE.

Comment: You misread or incorrectly disbelieved the question.  The mention of distinct JTAG interfaces makes it clear that the question is really talking about distinct FPGAs in peripherals, not about the chip implementing the computer on which Linux is running.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I found two references: https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp058.pdf and (x)svflib. The first link describes xilinx's reference code. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If the peripherals are registered as devices and have appropriate drivers to access them, you may be able to just `cat` the images to them.

For example, on a Zedboard you can do the following to program the FPGA from Linux:

```
cat myfpgaimage.bit > /dev/xdevcfg
```

https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Embedded-Linux/Zynq-Loading-bitfile-into-FPGA-from-Linux-xdevcfg/td-p/237850